# how can i make this bruteforce algorithm multithreaded?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork, brute-force

how can i make this bruteforce algorithm multithreaded? If i launch this it uses only one cpu. How can i parallelize this? It seems impossible. It's ok with fork or with pthread for me. This code makes a bruteforce to invert an hash, it generates all possibile strings, makes the hash and compares with the digest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "attacchi.h"
#include "hash.h"

void iterazione(char *stringa, int index, int lunghezza);

char *checksum,*hashType;

void bruteforce(char digest[],char tipohash[]) {
    checksum = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    hashType = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    strcpy(checksum,digest);
    strcpy(hashType,tipohash);
    int lunghezza, i;
    printf("Inserire la lunghezza massima da testare: ");
    scanf("%d", &lunghezza);
    char stringa[lunghezza + 1];
    memset(stringa, 0, lunghezza + 1);
    for (i = 1; i <= lunghezza; i++) {
        iterazione(stringa, 0, lunghezza);
    }
}

void iterazione(char *stringa, int index, int lunghezza) {
    char c;
    if (index < (lunghezza - 1)) {
        for (c = ' '; c <= '~'; ++c) {
            stringa[index] = c;
            iterazione(stringa, index + 1, lunghezza);
        }
    } else {
        for (c = ' '; c <= '~'; ++c) {
            stringa[index] = c;
            stringa[index+1] = '\n';
            if(strcmp(hash(stringa,hashType),checksum)==0) {
                printf("Trovato!\nhash %s %s -> %s\n", checksum, hashType, stringa);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to modify your algorithm to take advantage of multiple threads would be instead of starting the recursion with a call to `iterazione(stringa, 0, lunghezza)`, start it with a call that selects the first character from a range then calls `iterazione(stringa, 1, lunghezza)`:

```
void avvia_iterazione(char iniziale, char finale, int lunghezza)
{
    char c;
    char stringa[lunghezza + 1] = "";

    for (c = iniziale; c <= finale; ++c) {
            stringa[0] = c;
            iterazione(stringa, 1, lunghezza);
    }
}
```

You then call `avvia_iterazione()` with different, non-overlapping ranges of characters in each thread (eg. if you have two threads, you might call `avvia_iterazione(' ', 'O');` in one and `avvia_iterazione('P', '~');` in the other.

(You'll need to make sure that `lunghezza >= 2` as well).